# What I should select to start for developing angular 2 web application from Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am going to develop the web application from Angular 2. I have completed till step 1 as it mentioned in angular 2 document https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. Now What should be the next step to create the web application using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also special chapter for Visual Studio 2015 QuickStart

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

See also

- http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=angular2&doctypeid=1%3b2%3b3%3b13%3b14&sort=createddesc
- https://blog.sstorie.com/0-60-with-angular-2-and-visual-studio-part-2/
- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Answer (score 1):

If you are also planning on using IIS, IIS Express or Kestrel to serve your files. I would recommend checking out this article:
http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/
By doing this you can run C# code before serving your static files. You could also have an API running in C# etc.

If you are planning on running node's lite-server like angular2 tutorials I would follow:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html
as @yurzui mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work on rubymines for angular

Comment: this should be as comment , not sufficient for answer i think

Answer (score 0):

we can do the following step:-

1. Go to create new project
2. Select c# => Asp.net Web application=> Empty Website
3. Now Add the package.json,system.config.js,tsconfig.json,typings.json files as it it is given in angular officail website https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
4. Now go to your command prompt and change the path to your project location that we can get by simply right click to our project file and select open folder in file explorer
5. After changing the location now write **npm install**, this command will install all the packages of angular 2 in node_modules files which is hidden file, we can see this folder by clicking show all file icon present in top of our project menu. 
   6.One more folder typings should also be added as hidden file,if it is not added then write the command **npm run typings install**

By above steps our angular environment is setup, now we can enjoy developing our Angular 2 project.